# How to install/build c++ boost library on VS code for windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, boost

Being new to programming I'm struggling to install the boost library. I use the VS code IDE and run windows 10. The compiler I use is MinGW (mingw64), from msys2.

After reading a lot of "tutorial" or related topics I still don't manage to build boost library and this taking me a lot of time, so it would very much appreciated if someone could help me out.

He is what I have done:

1. download the boost library "boost_1_79_0"
2. Unzip the file in C:/DevSoft
3. Try to build it via the cmd by writing in the correct directory: `bootstrap v143`
   according to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5afpq2TkOHc

Here is the answer/error I get on cmd:

```
Building Boost.Build engine LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local could not find "vswhere" Call_If_Exists "..\bin\VCVARS32.BAT"
###
### Using 'msvc' toolset.
###

C:\DevSoft\boost_1_79_0\tools\build\src\engine>"cl" /nologo /MP /MT /TP /Feb2 /wd4996 /O2 /GL /EHsc   -DNDEBUG  builtins.cpp class.cpp command.cpp compile.cpp constants.cpp cwd.cpp debug.cpp debugger.cpp execcmd.cpp execnt.cpp execunix.cpp filent.cpp filesys.cpp fileunix.cpp frames.cpp function.cpp glob.cpp hash.cpp hcache.cpp hdrmacro.cpp headers.cpp jam.cpp jamgram.cpp lists.cpp make.cpp make1.cpp md5.cpp mem.cpp modules.cpp native.cpp object.cpp option.cpp output.cpp parse.cpp pathnt.cpp pathsys.cpp pathunix.cpp regexp.cpp rules.cpp scan.cpp search.cpp jam_strings.cpp startup.cpp subst.cpp sysinfo.cpp timestamp.cpp variable.cpp w32_getreg.cpp modules/order.cpp modules/path.cpp modules/property-set.cpp modules/regex.cpp modules/sequence.cpp modules/set.cpp /link kernel32.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib '"cl"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\DevSoft\boost_1_79_0\tools\build\src\engine>dir *.exe  Volume in drive C is Windows  Volume Serial Number is 76EC-76E7

 Directory of C:\DevSoft\boost_1_79_0\tools\build\src\engine

File Not Found

C:\DevSoft\boost_1_79_0\tools\build\src\engine>copy /b .\b2.exe .\bjam.exe The system cannot find the file specified.

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
```

I'd like to metion that I of course have a compiler install and that I can run and compile code properly in VS code.

Anyone that could give me clear instruction on how to finally get this library installed ? Keep in mind that I have already visited related topics but I couldn't progress from it.

Thanks,

Antoine

Comment: You using VSC doesn't matter. What matters is the compiler you use. MinGW or MSVC? If MinGW, where did you install it from?

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! the compiler I use is MinGW (mingw64), from msys2.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HD0pqVtsmw

Comment: Good choice. Then you should be able to install prebuilt boost using `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-boost`.

Comment: Alright thanks. Could you give me further indication to proceed ? is it to write in command line or else ?

Comment: To install a compiler in msys2, you already had to use `pacman`, so should know where to type it: in msys2 terminal.